# 20.2 volts on the B+ terminal of a12v alternator.

Tags: alternator, charging

The engine on my sailboat has an Iskra 12-volt alternator that has worked fine for over 3,000 hours of operation.  Just recently, I noticed that the voltmeter shows no charging, ie, only about 12 volts with the engine running at cruising RPM.   However, a hand- held VOM shows 20.2 volts at the Battery + terminal when the engine is running.  Any ideas?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: try a different VOM to be sure it is not an erroneous reading.

Comment: When the engine is not running what is the voltage at the B+ terminal - ie has that wire become broken or disconnected from the battery? Or is it loose or have a corroded connection?

Comment: BTW, Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!